# getTotalLength() returns 0 on path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have run into what seems to be an unusual issue.

When I use `d3.select('#pathid').node().getTotalLength()` and run the file straight my computer's SSD, it works fine. However, when I put it on a server and try to run it, that line always returns 0. Even on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kicker10bog/pen/xxbmqXG).

If anyone has any suggestions, I would be grateful.

Comment: Hey Jason, please share some code (path plus full d3 for example) on here and/or codepen so that we can replicate it.

Comment: there's a codepen link in the original question.

Comment: My Bad!! I (wrongly) thought it was a generic link to codepen. However, I took a look and it works fine for me? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKBsu.png

Comment: heh, I figured out the problem. It was the Brave browser's "shields" preventing it from working right. .... strange that it would only affect that one function and just cause it to return 0. 

Thanks for your time, Alex!

Comment: awesome. Very cool demo btw! I was calculating curved paths the other day, lots of fun :)

Comment: Glad you like the demo! The final project will represent cyber attacks at the place I work. The data will come from logs we save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is a bit of a silly issue, but the problem was the "shields" in the Brave browser. Disabling them on codepen and the other server I was testing on made it work.

Comment: Argh. Ran into the same thing. Baffled as to why "shields" would affect this. Going back to Firefox + Ublock Origin...